# Send Parameters using Frame.Navigate in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

A class to temporarily store my input value here.

```
namespace App2
{
    class methC
    {
        public string tb1 { get; set; }
        public string tb2 { get; set; }
        public string tb3 { get; set; }
        public string tb4 { get; set; }
        public string tb5 { get; set; }
        public string tb6 { get; set; }

        public methC(string tb1, string tb2, string tb3)
        {
            this.tb1 = tb1;
            this.tb2 = tb2;
            this.tb3 = tb3;
            //this.right1 = right1;
            //this.right2 = right2;
            //this.right3 = right3;
            //this.Box = Box;
            //this.Grade = Grade; 
        }
    }
}
```

first page that take in the parameter

```
namespace App2
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            methC mc = new methC(tb1.Text, tb2.Text, tb3.Text);
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
        }


    }
}
```

How to get the data stored in tb1,tb2,tb3 to display in BlankPage1?

```
namespace App2
{
    public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
    {
        public BlankPage1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string four, five, six;
            four = tb4.Text;
            five = tb5.Text;
            six = tb6.Text;
            box.Text = four + five + six;
        }

        private void TextBlock_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

How's the thing suppose to work, MainPage take in 3 entry, store in methC and get from BlankPage to display tb1,tb2,tb3. How can i make this thing work?

Comment: Where do you want to display those values? Label? Textbox? or what?

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow Hi, im trying to display in textBlock(box named above).

Comment: @ZentTan Try saving your string variables in a collection/List and then display them by iterating on that list using **foreach**

Answer (score 8):

As long as you Navigate to another page using a `Type` parameter you can't use a constructor to pass the data. so Microsoft provided another way of doing that work.

You can pass your object using this overload of Navigate function:

```
        methC mc = new methC(tb1.Text, tb2.Text, tb3.Text);
        string Param = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mc);
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), Param);
```

override OnNavigatedTo in the BlankPage1:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
     methC myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<methC>((string)e.Parameter);

     Labelx.Text = myData.x;
     , ....

     base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
 }
```

this is from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages)

and the worst case is to assign them through static members, so in the BlankPage1 class you can add:

```
 public static methC Data { get; set; } 

 public BlankPage1()
 {
      mylabel.Text = Data.X;
      , ....
 }
```

and you can assign the values before Navigation:

```
        methC mc = new methC(tb1.Text, tb2.Text, tb3.Text);
        BlankPage1.Data = mc;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
```

Comment: Hi, i am having error on the GetNavigationState() part any idea what's going on?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the post and you can use it. I also updated MSDN's link  and the new Link is more clear than previous one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages

Comment: How can i reuse the data inside OnNavigatedTo?

Comment: put a BreakPoint on this function to see **e.Parameter** it should be a string like this "{\"tb1\":\"...\", \"tb2\":\"...\",  ...... }" if you see that, then as the above code explained you need to deserialize it and assign the values of methC to your controls.

Answer (score 2):

In your mainpage, you can pass the parameter of the class object directly.

```
methC mc = new methC(tb1.Text, tb2.Text, tb3.Text);
Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), mc);
```

In your next page, you can receive it as a class object

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        methC item = e.Parameter as methC;
    }
```